# GREP to find capital T not preceded by a full stop and a space in InDesign

Tags: grep, adobe-indesign

I have a document that has lots of capital letter Ts (The A&E Department, The Post Office). I want to find all instances of a capital T when not preceded by a full point and a space so I can change the capital T to a small t.

I tried:

(?<!.~.)[T]

and

(?<!.~.)T

which I thought should find all Ts not preceded by a full point and a space. However, both find *all* capital Ts, the negative lookbehind seems to be ignored.

I'm fairly new to GREP and I've spent a few hours Googling and tried lots of different variations but these seem to me that they should work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have `GNU grep`, you need to use `grep -P` for lookarounds to work. And based on your description, I think you want `(?<!\. )T` which will match `T` only if not preceded by a `.` and space character sequence

Comment: Also, if you want *change* something, you need `sed`, `perl`, etc... not `grep` (unless you are using `ripgrep`)

Comment: @Sundeep your answer works for InDesign's implementation of grep I tried `(?<!\. )T` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

`(?<!\. )T` which will match `T` only if not preceded by a `.` and a space character sequence.

`.` is a metacharacter, so it has to be escaped for matching it literally

Comment: That's weird, I did have the backslash in my GREP, it just didn't come through to here when I pasted. Actually, it was working (~. also works rather than an actual space), I had just forgotten it would also find every T beginning a paragraph as well! Doh!

Soooo, I would have thought that:

(?<!\.~.)|(?<!^)T

or

(?<!\.~.|?<!^)T

would work but they don't. Maybe I can't add an 'or' to a negative lookbehind?

Comment: syntax is `(?<!pattern)` so you need to use `(?<!\. |^)T` (but that may run into variable length lookbehind issue).. you can use `(?<!\. )(?<!^)T` instead (there's no `|` here)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on how to format your code... in comments, surround the code snippet with backticks